# Fubini's theorem, interchanging order of integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

My question is, imagine I want to compute the following integral:
$$\int_A \int_B f(x,y)dxdy$$
and I decide to start from $x$ and get
$$\int_A \int_B f(x,y) dxdy <\infty.$$

On the contrary if I start from $y$ I get
$$\int_B\int_A f(x,y)dydx = \infty.$$

What is wrong here? which value of the integral should I trust? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what Fubini's theorem says, along with the Tonelli Theorem. Fubini's theorem says that if your function is absolutely integrable, then order of integration can be exchanged. Tonelli's theorem says that if you're integrating a non-negative function, you can always switch order of integration. So use Tonelli's theorem to show the integral is finite, hence apply Fubini's theorem to conclude order doesn't matter.

On the other hand, if one of your integrals gives $+\infty$, it should be easy to see that the same order of integration on $|f(x,y)|$ will also give infinity, so Fubini's theorem does NOT apply.

So, it's not a matter of *trusting* which integral is right. If you're integrating one way and you get infinity, *that*'s the answer for that order. The integral still exists, it's just equal to infinity. Whereas integrating the other way, maybe you get a finite answer, so *that* way gives you a finite answer. Ultimately they are *not the same integral*.

---

Comment: But in my case the function is positive and I get infinity when I integrate w.r.t. one variable and I get a finite value w.r.t. the other variable.

Comment: If your function is positive, the order of integration does not matter by Tonelli's theorem. So both integrals must be the same, meaning you made a mistake. They could both be finite, or both be infinity, but they have to be the same.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm afraid of :) I think I see the mistake actually, let us say that.. (the function is positive) I can't integrate w.r.t. one variable (it's difficult) but when I integrate w.r.t. the other I get a finite value, ergo the integral is finite no matter what.. right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If an integral is infinite, the statement "the integral exists" should be avoided.

Comment: I guess he means "exists" and it is infinite, in the sense that it exists, it is "something". Like limits, an infinite limit still exists.

Comment: So, only for "oscillating" sequences, the statement "the limit exists" is false ? In the case of divergent sequences, tending to infinite, I would not use the term "existing limit".

Comment: @Peter: You're right, the word "exists" is not right but it can certainly be defined to equal infinity, and of course not for something oscillating. The point is Tonelli's theorem hold when the integrals equal infinity: you get the same answer.